# header alignment issue - unable to fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to make the html table header fixed so that when user scrolls header is still be seen. I'm using bootstrap to display modal window. I tried using css, header is getting fixed but the header alignment is not correct. I know its pretty straight forward but unable to fix the header alignment issue. Please find the sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1408/)

html code:

```
  <div class="modal-body"  id="modal-body">
                       <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped"> <thead>
              <tr>
               <th style="width:14%;">Header1<th><th style="width:12%;">Header2</th><th style="width:19%;">Header3</th><th style="width:16%;">Header4</th>
              </tr></thead><tbody>
              <tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
              <tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
              ...</tbody></table>
```

css code:

```
.modal-body {
max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;
}

thead th {
height: 30px;

/*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
height: 120px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
/* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
width: 19.2%;
float: left;
}
```

Note:width in `<th>` is required. Each header is of different width in my application, so i should have that width assigned in `<th>`

Comment: remove the width style from th and they are working fine

Comment: @Satya - Ya that works, but i have multiple columns each column having different width.I should have that width option in <th>

Comment: then set width to something reasonable , as on 4% the text is being squeezed , how about 16% for rest of the columns as well

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap try this 
`<tr class="row"><th class="col-md-4">Header1</th><th class="col-md-4">Header2</th><th class="col-md-4">Header3</th><th class="col-md-4">Header4</th></tr>`

[Bootstrap/tables](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables)

Comment: Erdal - Please check the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1409/ . Still there is alignment issue with header when used bootstrap classes. And in my case i have multiple columns and each column width varies.